# Does 諸元{しょげん} mean "Specification" or "Various"?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to name a library on a group of forms. The specification names the group 諸元管理画面.

I tried to search and the dictionary says it means "various factors or elements".

But on other examples is says 諸元表 means specification sheet.

Any ideas what 諸元 means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naming a library for something related to computer programming?

According to [Weblio辞書](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%AB%B8%E5%85%83), yes, 諸元 can be used for "spec" (as in a language specification, etc.)

In other cases, 諸元 can be used about data for a particular item (the various parts or factors that make up an item, for example.)

As you know, words can have various meanings depending on the context; and it doesn't hurt to check. :)

Comment: Actually my manager keeps on saying it means master but I doubt that is what he meant.

Comment: @Nap maybe a "master" as in a "master spec"... or something?